# Adjusted beta for short positions, should we re-adjust the formula?

Tags: bloomberg, beta, hedge

I see in BBG that the beta of XSPS (an inverse SP500 ETF) to SPX Index is -1.05 and the adjusted beta is -0.37.

I get that -1.05 * 2/3 + 0.33 matches the adjusted beta. However, does this adjusted beta make sense for short positions? Should it not be -1.05 * 2/3 - 0.33 instead?

Comment: The adjusted formula is based on a Bayesian calculation that assumes the prior is 0. That shouldn't change if taking a short position.

Comment: Bloomberg's adjustment on a stock's historic beta appears to be based on the premise that a stock's beta moves toward the market average over time according to [this Bloomberg guide](https://guides.lib.byu.edu/c.php?g=216390&p=1428678). That means a short's beta is to move towards the opposite, i.e. -1.0, over time. So, it makes sense that the constant in the adjustment formula should be negative rather than positive for a short. However, I am not sure what the optimum terms in the formula should be if the historic beta is to come from the historic long rather than the historic short.